# Conversion of unreadable string from TCP IP port in java

Tags: java, serversocket

I am trying to read continuous data from TCP IP port of system using Java Socket Programming ServerSocket but I am getting unreadable string data like in following following image :

[image]

I am using following code for read data from TCP IP port :

```
 ServerSocket server_socket;
            BufferedReader input;
            try {
                server_socket = new ServerSocket(6666);
                LOGGER.info("Server waiting for client on port "
                        + server_socket.getLocalPort());
                System.out.println("Server waiting for client on port "
                        + server_socket.getLocalPort());
                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = server_socket.accept();

                    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    try {
                        while (true) {
                            String message = input.readLine();
                            if (message == null) {
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        socket.close();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

---

So please let me know what kind of data are in above image and what conversion I should do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What application is on the other end of the socket? Is the protocol it uses known? Can you include a hexadecimal representation of the received data instead of, or in addition to, text?

Comment: sorry I have no idea about other end protocol but it is hardware RFID reader device which sends data on configured server

Comment: In that case, barring any additional details you can offer, this is likely to turn into a reverse engineering problem. To that end, please include a hex representation of the received data, as it's far likely for someone familiar with a protocol to spot any magic numbers or patterns in that representation

Comment: and @nanofarad can you tell me what kind of data formate  it is?
what it is in encoded form ?

Comment: I don't know what data format it is or how it is encoded. If it is proprietary, you may need to fully reverse engineer it.

Comment: Do you have any documentation, including the manufacturer or the model/serial number of the device?

Answer (score 0):

One flaw:

The `InputStreamReader` is responsible for converting binary data (an InputStream) to a Reader ((Unicode) text). For that you can & should specify a text encoding, a Charset. You are using the default, platform encoding.

```
input = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
```

You can now access this server application yourself by **telnet** or an other terminal tool. Or even the browser by `http://localhost:6666/` (`telnet://localhost:6666/`?).

What you are seeing does look like non-text binary data - should the default encoding not be Chinese or such.

Furthermore the code would be improved by a new thread from a thread pool handling the `socket` from the `accept`.

One should pay attention to the header lines one sends (you do not output) and then receive.

Comment: "The port 6666 is for TCP/UDP" What do you mean by this? UDP and TCP are two completely different protocols

Comment: @Joni you are right; that TCP and UDP are different things entirely I was aware of, but the remembered port number is not correct either. Thanks, removed